# How to swap columns in eigen3 SparseMatrix

Tags: eigen, eigen3

What is an efficient way to swap columns in a ColMajor eigen SparseMatrix?

I have tried the following:

```
SparseMatrix<mpz_class,ColMajor> H;
SparseVector<mpz_class> v;

// Somehow initialize H.

v = H.col(i);
H.col(i) = H.col(j);
H.col(j) = v;
```

which I think is not correct (assignment doesn't make a copy I assume?)  I don't actually understand why this doesn't work, while e.g. the following does seem to work as intended:

```
v = H.col(i); w = H.col(j);
H.col(i) = s*v + t*w;  // s, t are some mpz_class elements.
```

A way which actually works is:

```
SparseMatrix<mpz_class,ColMajor> H, H_;
PermutationMatrix<Dynamic,Dynamic> P;
P.setIdentity();
P.applyTranspositionOnTheRight(i,j);
H_ = H; H = H_ * P;
```

Now this I assume makes a copy of the entire matrix H?  So I would prefer the first method, or some efficient `H *= P` in place permutation.  Or something like `swap(H.col(i),H.col(j))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the first version is that H is being partly modified before reading to the H.col(j) object (which is now invalid). You can workaround by copying both columns first:

```
Hi = H.col(i);
Hj = H.col(j);
H.col(i) = Hj;
H.col(j) = Hi;
```

Of course, it would be better to support `H.col(i).swap(H.col(j))` as for dense matrices...

Also, if you apply numerous swap, then better fill them in a `Eigen::Transpositions`, convert it to a `Eigen::PermutationMatrix` and apply it once (or directly compute a unique permutation).

Comment: Thanks!  So if I understand correctly, assignment does make a copy and the problem lies in the line `H.col(i) = H.col(j);` because it manipulates the matrix while reading from it?  And if so, does the same problem exist for the in-place manipulations like `H.col(i) -= H.col(j)`?